# How can I hide the /web/ directory in symfony 2 (remote server)

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, web

This is the url address: http://pirintourist.coxslot.com/web/

I want to remove web/ from my url

This is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why dont you move your symfony app one level up in your directory structure?

Comment: So all resources outside the web folder aren't accessible. It's an extra layer of security

Answer (score 0):

You can override the web directory and move it to different location.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory